# Integral of $\frac{2}{x^3-x^2}$

Tags: integration

How can I integrate $\dfrac2{x^3-x^2}$? Can someone please give me some hints? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac2{x^3-x^2}=\frac2{x^2(x-1)}=\frac{A}x+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x-1}$$

for what values of $A,B$, and $C$?

Comment: @darkchampionz: No, because it’s essential to combine the partial fractions over their **lowest** common denominator, which is always the original denominator; you’ve combined them over $x^3(x-1)$ instead. I make it $A=B=-2$, $C=2$.

Comment: @darkchampionz: Yes, that looks *much* better. :-)

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Think partial fractions.

(for more hints, please ask!)

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac2{x^3-x^2}\, dx =\frac2{x^2(x-1)}= \int \left(\frac{A}x+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x-1}\right)\,dx$$

$$Ax(x-1) + B(x-1) + Cx^2 = 2$$

We choose values for $x$ that "zero out" some of the terms, to simplifying the computation of the unknown values $A, B, C$:

$$x = 1 \implies A(1)(1 - 1) + B(1-1) + C(1^2) = 2 \iff  0 + 0 + C = 2\quad \checkmark$$

$$x = 0 \implies B(-1) = 2 \implies B = -2\quad \checkmark$$

$$x = 2, C = 2, B = -2 \implies 2A - 2 + 8 = 2\iff A = -2\quad \checkmark$$

$$ \int \left(\frac{A}x+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x-1}\right)\,dx = \int \left(-\frac{2}x -\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x-1}\right)\,dx$$ $$ =-2 \int \frac{dx}x \quad -\quad  2\int \frac{dx}{x^2}\quad + \quad 2 \int \frac{dx}{x-1}$$